# How can I compare times when a time for a day has passed (over 23:59)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wrote code that compares times on an if statement. Times are represented as strings.

```
//evaluates to true
if (time > startingTime && time < endingTime) 
//time = "2230" startingTime = "2200" endingTime = "2330"
```

This is fine, unless the endingTime has gone over 23:39

```
//evaluates to false
if (time > startingTime && time < endingTime) 
//time="2230" startingTime = "2200" endingTime = "0030"
```

I was wondering if there's a quick way to fix this that I haven't thought of.

Alternatively, This is how I am using Moment.js to set the times, and I thought perhaps there would be a way to add a 'day' parameter so that this could be fixed

```
const endingTime = moment(startingTime, 'HH:mm')
            .add(minutesToAdd, 'minutes')
            .format('HHmm') //outputs the time an event ends
                            //after adding its duration to its starting time
```

But then, the final formating would have to be fixed (I guess), as well as the startingTime -- so that those could be compared later. I have not yet found a way to do this in the Moment.js library documentation.

Comment: It will be 24:00:00 which is the same as 00:00:00 but on a different date. So you also need to compare the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more a question of logic than moment.js library configuration: I don't think can exist a moment.js setting to solve it.
You don't have the day as a reference, but just hour; you clearly assume that the start is before the end... And that you can consider a maximum cycle of 24 hours.
At this point you have to figure out if you are thinking about midnight or if you are on the same day. I think you need that kind of reasoning:

```
if (startingTime < endingTime) // you are in the same day
{
    if (time > startingTime && time < endingTime)
    {
        ...
    }
}
else  // startingTime>endingTime: it means ending time is after the midnight
{
    if ( (time > startingTime && time <= 2359) || (time > 0 && time < endingTime) )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope I understand your problem and that this will help you.

---

Let me add a little draw to explain that simple logic better..
[image: compare time in start and end after the midnight]

Comment: would you explain why the second condition ```(time > 0 && time < endingTime)``` is necessary on the if statement inside of else (last if statement of all)?

Comment: The outer if (startingTime < endingTime) let you know if you are in the same day; in case else you assume that the endingTime is in the next day. So, in the last if statment, you have to discover if your time is before the endingTime. In fact the correct condition do not neet time>0000 ... It will always true, I write it only for let you understand the logic.The last if can be only (time>startingTime AND time<2359) OR (time<endingTime). I hope I was able to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You have no way of knowing whether the times are within the scope of one day unless you use date and time.

**Moment.js solution:**

```
const startingTime = moment();
const endingTime = moment(startingTime)
        .add(minutesToAdd, 'minutes');
```

**Plain JS solution (Epoch):**

```
const startingTime = Date.now();
const endingTime = startingTime + minutesToAdd * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: I am not using the startingTime as the current time, I am using a set time, as, e.g. "2200". How would I then pass it to moment?

Comment: moment().hour(22).minutes(00);